# neo4j - output in json format

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-bolt

I recently upgraded from Neo4j 3.1.4 to 3.2.3 and I notice that the browser has lost the exportJSON option. How can I export the result of a cypher query as JSON in the new version?